To Change order of X labels for dynamic labels in ggplot2
I want to customize x-axis label in ggplot2.
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)
df = data.frame(SUBJID = 1001:1010,
                Level = sample(c("Normal", "Mild", "Moderate", "Severe"), 10, replace = T),
                Value = runif(10, min = 200, max = 500))

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(Level, Value)) +
  geom_boxplot()


For known X label, usually I use this code to change order.
df$Level = factor(df$Level, levels = c("Normal", "Mild", "Moderate", "Severe"))
  
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(Level, Value)) +
  geom_boxplot()


But I added the subject number in X label, so the label is not a known character.
df %>%
  group_by(Level) %>%
  mutate(
    SUBJN = n_distinct(SUBJID),
    Level_N = paste(Level, "(N=", SUBJN, ")")
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Level_N, Value)) +
  geom_boxplot()


The X label is not a fixed character, so I cannot use the code I previously used.
How to customize order of X label in this situation?
I tried fct_reorder, and the plot was not what I wanted.
df %>%
  group_by(Level) %>%
  mutate(
    SUBJN = n_distinct(SUBJID),
    Level_N = paste(Level, "(N=", SUBJN, ")") |> factor() |> fct_reorder(as.numeric(Level))
  ) %>%
  boxplot(Value ~ Level_N)



Maybe just step by step and use the correct way to change label of axis.
Data is data, label is label.
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)
df = data.frame(SUBJID = 1001:1010,
                Level = sample(c("Normal", "Mild", "Moderate", "Severe"), 10, replace = T),
                Value = runif(10, min = 200, max = 500))

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(Level, Value)) +
  geom_boxplot()

df$Level = factor(df$Level, levels = c("Normal", "Mild", "Moderate", "Severe"))

## custom x axis labels by using scale_x_discrete

label_data <- df %>%
  group_by(Level) %>%
  summarise(SUBJN = n_distinct(SUBJID))

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(Level, Value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = paste0(label_data$Level, " (N=", label_data$SUBJN, ")"))


Oh, good idea! We can plot with the order of Level first, then add the number of subject. Thanks a lot!
